# Is it possible to have an app displaying as a bottom sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building an app which accepts a deeplink from other apps to perform a functionality, and it would be much nicer if i could just display the app as a bottom sheet on top of the other app that calls the deeplink.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xL3zE.png

Is it possible to do this in iOS?

Comment: The answer is: No

Comment: This may be an [app clip](https://developer.apple.com/app-clips/) usage, it depends on what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

As I know iOS doesn't support displaying apps as overly or on the top of the other app. Maybe writing custom keyboard extension is the way to reach your goal.

Try this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/49-custom-keyboard-extensions-getting-started

I hope it will help you.